# Why can't I light a LED with a 1.5 V battery?

Tags: led, solid-state-devices, joule-thief

The LED I am using requires a higher voltage to light than I have supplied, and as a result, it doesn't light at all.

I would expect at least a dim light, but light is not generated.

Why this behavior of "if there isn't the required voltage level there's no light"? What is going on inside the LED?

Comment: *I would expect at least a dim light* Why would you expect that? The process that generates the photons only starts above a certain voltage/current. So how can photons be generated when the required conditions are not met? Do you understand **how** an LED works? If not: research it. It will then become obvious what is needed for the LED to produce light.

Comment: LEDs that are lit using a single 1.5V battery are also equipped with a boost driver. It can be self oscillating for cheap low power LEDs, or IC driven for more powerful LEDs.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie It's reasonable to assume an LED works like an incandescent light bulb if you've never encountered anything that would tell you otherwise.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: The next step after reaching that point is to open a book and read about what LEDs are and how they work, surely? That's "my assumption is apparently wrong" management 101.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That would be a reasonable approach for someone that's not a complete newbie in EE. Since on this site we allow questions from newbies and enthusiasts, sometimes you come across questions like this one, which are clearly posted by people that don't even know how/where to begin with EE. After all, there are even some manufacturers that market their LED as a ["SOLID STATE LAMP"](http://www.kingbrightusa.com/images/catalog/SPEC/WP1513GC.pdf) (as they were some kind of light bulb of the past) in their datasheet. Confusion in a newbie is understandable in this case.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati: I think it's a reasonable approach for anybody who's finished a junior level of education. You do not need to be an expert in a subject to know that when your assumptions fall apart you can open a book and learn more about the topic. I will never understand the claim that you have to be an expert to know the basics of learning.

Comment: [Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=poWJTSV4Yio) of Ben Eater toying with an LED and a variable power source. Might be worth a look.

Comment: Even a lightbulb won't give off a very dim light if you only supply it with a very low voltage.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit *"I will never understand the claim that you have to be an expert to know the basics of learning."* I understand your point, but if this statement were true, teachers would have all lost their jobs since the inception of the Internet. Luckily for me (I'm a teacher, now), that has not happened yet! :-) You would be surprised how many people lack the most basic learning strategy, despite their enthusiasm in doing something.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "*The next step after reaching that point is to open a book and read about what LEDs are and how they work, surely?*" I think the 2017 version of that process is to get on electronics.stackexchange.com and ask how LEDs are different from incandescent bulbs. I've actually put almost all of my books in storage, since I literally never use them any more. The Internet is one of the new "basics of learning". This is absolutely the right place for such a question.

Comment: When I posted my question I wanted an answer that a novice could grasp, that's why I chose Lorenzo's answer, but I let anyone that wanted to include further information when I included "what is going on inside the LED". Even a simple  phenomenon can be quite complex, depending on how deeply you explain it. Do you think that leftaroundabout's answer was basic?

Comment: Not flagging as such, but looks pretty much a duplicate of [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/55823/how-can-i-efficiently-drive-an-led)

Comment: @clabacchio Well, I don't think this question is a real duplicate of the question you linked to (albeit similar). In this latter the OP knows that it is unwise to connect an LED directly to a battery. This question is clearly from a beginner with a slightly lower level of expertise on the subject.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati I agree, the thing is that there should be a go-to question for these simple problems, as they always get a lot of attention and don't produce so much value IMO (the infamous bikeshed)

Comment: @Sadly it is a limitation of the system and the way new users learn to use the site. The "duplicate system" doesn't account for different levels of expertise and the Q&A format doesn't lend itself to building multi-level tutorials.

Comment: I had to mark this one as favorite

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Book and book! What is book?

Comment: @LorenzoDonati And yet they manage to find their way on here and post to the correct group.  If they can do that, why can't they type "led voltage" into Google and look at anything on the first page, when that is significantly easier?  If I can JFGI without needing to know any complicated search words, then they have *not* done enough self-help to be asking a smart question.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

LEDs don't work like ordinary (incandescence) light bulbs.

Main differences (a bit simplified for very beginners):

- They have a polarity, hence they must be powered using DC respecting that polarity. Reverse the polarity and they won't work. You may also damage them if you apply more than ~4V-5V in the reverse direction (these are safe values; the exact maximum tolerable value depends on the specific device).
- Light emission begins only if a certain voltage is reached (threshold voltage), under that voltage the emission is negligible. Therefore, if you have a battery whose voltage is below the threshold voltage of the LED, you are out of luck, unless you use a more complicated circuit (e.g. a [Joule thief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_thief) or a boost DC-DC converter) to power the LED.
- After the threshold voltage is reached, *any **very slight** increase in voltage makes the LED conduct heavily, i.e. absorb a **huge current***. Hence you need a resistor in series to limit that current to a safe limit. There are other questions/answers on this site explaining how to calculate the value of the limiting resistor.
- Once conducting, the light intensity emitted is roughly *proportional to the current* (not voltage) that flows in the diode (so you get a brighter LED if you decrease the value of the limiting resistor). This up to the maximum current limit of the LED. After that limit has been reached, the device goes *POOF*!

You also ask why all this happens, but the answer is fairly complex, since it depends on the physical structure of the semiconductor crystal inside the diode. The physical explanation lies in quantum mechanics and solid-state physics, really tough subjects.

The [Wikipedia article on LEDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode) only scrapes the surface of the [internal workings of the LEDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode#Working_principle) and still is fairly complex.

Comment: This is interesting to me. When I was poor I made an electrical continuity tester from an LED and a AA battery. Well, I was amazed at how quickly the battery ran down; this explains it so thanks.

Comment: Yes.  The interesting thing is that until the threshold voltage is reached, an LED is effectively an open circuit - no current.  Once it is passed, it's effectively a short circuit - meaning infinite current (assuming ideal wires, of course).  Which is why circuitry using LEDs will always have a resistor in series with the LED.  The resistor determines the current (voltage/resistance) and the current determines the brightness of the LED.  In general always use a resistor with an LED and use the largest one that will produce the brightness you require, to minimize power consumption.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "absorb a huge current", absorb sounds like the current vanishes in the LED - which it does not, it passes through it.

Comment: @Arsenal please, reread my post, (1) I explicitly marked my points as *"simplified for very beginners"*; (2) *current absorption* is a perfectly valid engineering term, although maybe not so common. See the abstract of [this IEEE article](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7147120/).

Comment: @Arsenal moreover, the more common expression "to draw a current" has a more or less the same meaning and "ambiguity". [This EE.SE answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/95922/29434) is relevant :-)

Comment: @Arsenal Of course also "the device goes POOF" and "emitting magic smoke" is standard jargon! :-)

Comment: @arsenal technically it does. Power is converted into heat and light. Absorbed isn't a horrible description.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati hmm, I've never heard it before, and I find little usage on the net. Most of the occurrences I found had to do with dielectric absorption and the current because of it (the linked IEEE article as well). I did realize that your answer is catered in that way, for me it doesn't provide a simplification, instead it introduces a term which is not that widely used (compare a search to current absorption and current draw). I'm fine with learning something new.

Comment: @Arsenal, as I said, I didn't use it because it was common (indeed, it isn't, as we both agree upon), but because for a complete beginner it gives the right idea of "drawing-in" or "demanding" more current. I also guessed that the OP, by his name, is not a native English speaker (I may be wrong, though): in these cases I tend to prefer English words derived from Latin, instead of their Anglo-saxon counterparts, in the hope they can "lower the impedance mismatch" between English and the OP's language.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati seems like we have different ideas about educating people. I like to introduce them to the words we actually use to make researching and expressing oneself easier in the future, but I can also see your point. Current and voltage is just a hard thing to explain.

Comment: If you have some kind of variable current (potentiometer, current limiting power supply, etc) you can observe that LED will not go POOF immediately, instead LED will be damaged over time. Light intensity will drop, color will change (e.g. green to yellow-ish) and only then the LED will release magic smoke. Rather amusing experimet :)

Comment: @friendzis Yep! controlled destruction of an LED is an interesting torture example :-) Of course, when speaking with a complete newbie I engage my "belt and braces" mode with big red flags sporting a "don't this at home" writing :-D

Comment: @DavidC. No need for a specific series resistor for the LED if you have a current-limited power supply. The goal is to limit the current; a series resistor is just *one* way of accomplishing that.

Comment: @DiegoAlves [Obligatory video of letting the magic smoke out of an LED](https://youtu.be/DHxI9beaUrU) for educational purposes regarding too much voltage :)

Comment: @DavidC. - "Once it is passed, it's effectively a short circuit - meaning infinite current (assuming ideal wires, of course)." Not even remotely true. The incremental resistance gets low, but I can assure you from personal experience that it's perfectly possible to drive an LED from a voltage source and get usable results - in the short term. Dealing with temperature shifts is no end of tricky, and usually ends badly. But an LED is not remotely a short circuit in its operating range.

Answer (score 56):

I see Lorenzo has already answered your question directly (+1).  Here is what you can do to light your LED and see what you've got.

LEDs are diodes, so conduct only in one direction.  Unlike a ordinary light bulb, orientation matters.  If the LED doesn't light one way, flip it around and try again.

To safely experiment with pretty much any LED, use a 5 V supply with at least 180 Ω in series.  Using a higher resistance works, but will light the LED more dimly.  Even with 1 kΩ in series, you will still be able to see any visible-light LED light up indoors.

The reason to use a 5 V supply is to limit the reverse voltage across the LED when connected backwards.  Most LEDs can stand at least 5 V reverse across them.

A visible-light LED will drop a minimum of 1.8 V.  That leaves (5 V)-(1.8 V) = 3.2 V across the resistor.  Just about any LED can handle 20 mA forward current.  By Ohm's law, (3.2 V)/(20 mA) = 160 Ω.  I said 180 Ω minimum for a little margin and because that is a common value.

LED forward voltage is dependent on color.  Common green LEDs drop about 2.1 V, for example.  "White" LEDs are usually really UV LEDs with phosphors that re-emits in the visible spectrum.  Those can drop around 3.5 V.

With a 200 Ω resistor and a 3.5 V LED, you get (1.5 V)/(200 Ω) = 7.5 mA.  Such a LED will still light quite visibly with 7.5 mA thru it, even if it could have handled 20 mA or more.

Once you get your LED to light, you can measure its forward voltage, then adjust the resistor to allow the maximum current with that forward voltage.  Assume the maximum is 20 mA unless you have a datasheet and it says otherwise.

Comment: I love this answer. Lorenzo answered like a _scientist_, but you nailed it like an _engineer_!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69047/discussion-on-answer-by-olin-lathrop-why-cant-i-light-a-led-with-a-1-5v-battery). Or perhaps start a Meta discussion

Comment: Worth bearing in mind that phrases like _"with at least 180 Ω in series"_ could be very confusing to newbies who might be unsure whether you mean something advanced that they don't about or whether you mean to literally just whack a 180ohm resistor into the circuit.

Comment: I would have them start with 330 Ohm.  Why blast the LED with so much current?

Answer (score 36):

## Physics explanation

#### Light bulbs

Incandescent light isn't really a light source so much as *a heating element*. Any current through a wire [heats it up a bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_heating) ([Joule's Law of Heating](https://protonstalk.com/thermal-effects-of-electricity/joules-law-of-heating/)); once the wire is above room temperature it emits net energy via [black-body radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation). The rate at which this energy is emitted depends [on the fourth power of temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law), i.e. the higher the temperature the brighter<sup>†</sup>. And the more current (or [equivalently<sup>‡</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) more voltage), the higher the temperature of the wire.

The fundamental physical process behind blackbody light emission is this: the atoms in a warm piece of material are shaken around by thermal motion. This motion is completely chaotic, so even if the average energy per atom is rather low, every once in a while an atom at the surface will get a push from multiple neighbours and thus gather enough energy that it can emit a visible photon (at least \$2.6\times10^{-19}\$ Joules). But far more often, it will only have enough energy to emit an invisible infrared photon.

#### LEDs

By contrast, LEDs pump the atoms *directly* to the energy that's required for emitting visible light. They do this by cleverly exploiting the [band gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_gap) of a semiconductor. That's a quantum-mechanical feature of crystals like silicon, which “forbids” electrons from having energies in a certain range. You then take one piece of semiconductor which has been [doped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doping_(semiconductor)) so the conductance electrons are all *above* the band gap, and one where they're all below the bandgap. Then, when a current flows across the junction, each electron loses just the right amount of energy to excite an atom to produce a photon with the right energy to be visible – again, for red light, this is about \$2.6\ldots3.2\times10^{-19}\$ Joules.

Only... why would the electrons continue to go over the junction? After an electron has crossed the junction, it won't be inclined to climb across the band gap again; that costs energy which the electron doesn't have.
...Unless you give it the energy from an external source: each volt that you apply to a circuit can supply an electron with an energy of \$1.6\times10^{-19}\:\mathrm{J}\$, a quantity that physicists call just [an electron volt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronvolt). So when you apply a voltage of \$U\$ to an LED whose band gap has an energy of \$U\times1\:\mathrm{eV}\$, you can keep up a current. This voltage isn't really dependent on *how much* current actually passes through the LED, therefore the brightness can't effectively be regulated by tweaking the voltage – you need to regulate the *current* instead. And if the voltage falls below the band gap, the current will just cease entirely, because the conductance electrons just won't go into the *n*-doped domain at all anymore.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>That's a bit too simplistic: Stefan-Boltzmann describes the intensity integrated over the entire electromagnetic spectrum. Only a narrow band of that is actually visible (that's the reason incandescent light is so much less efficient than LEDs). Since the wavelength of peak intensity [also depends on the temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien%27s_displacement_law), brightness is in fact related not just to \$T^4\$ but to a more complicated relation, but still: higher temperatures always correspond to brighter light.</sub>

<sup>‡</sup><sub>Similarly, Ohm's law isn't completely correct here because the resistivity depends on temperature. But the qualitative dependency higher voltage ⇒ higher electrical power still holds true.</sub>

Answer (score 15):

You just got an object lesson in how LEDs are *non-linear*.

Incandescent bulbs are linear *once they light*.  Linear means it acts like a resistor: current draw is in proportion to voltage: half the voltage, half the current, 1/4 the power.  An incandescent light would do what you expect.

LEDs have a very steep voltage-current curve: a small change in voltage results in a large change in current draw.  You are off the bottom of that chart, hence no light.

The steep curve makes the LED very jumpy, small voltage changes result in big (and damaging) current changes.  Worse, the curve changes based on temperature, binning and age.  So LEDs are rated at a specific *current* rather than voltage.  For indicators, you can limit current with resistors.  For lighting, where you need peak performance, it's best to use an active driver circuit to regulate the current to spec.

Such circuits also lend themselves to boosting or bucking supply voltage to suit the LED. The Joule Thief is a simple circuit that solves the problem of driving a lighting LED with a single 1.5V battery.

---

For what it's worth, it's even worse with the third kind of light, arc-discharge lighting: fluorescent, neon, metal halide, mercury vapor, and high/low pressure sodium. They are insulators up until a certain voltage when the arc strikes... After which they are nearly a dead short. Current limiting is mandatory.

Comment: I was taught that a filament bulb made a reasonable constant-current load, the hotter it burns, the higher the resistance. Maybe this is what you mean by 'once they light'.

Comment: @SeanHoulihane Yes, until a filament lights, it's near a dead short, and still has a considerable "inrush current" until it reaches full power.  If you use an incandescent in a current-limited mode, you can do a lot of stuff like that. For chuckles, put an incandescent on a CC supply and watch it warm up slowly.

Answer (score 7):

A little background on semiconductors...

**Pure** silicon(or germanium) is an insulator. Impurities are added to create "P" or "N" type material. When these are next to each other (in a P N diode or LED) the impurities effectively *cancel each other out*, leaving  you with a small "**pure**" layer - that acts as an insulator.

If you hook up power the **wrong** way, the layer gets thicker and stronger - right up until you damage the device. (Varicaps use this principle to create a variable capacitor - thickness of insulation acts like distance between capacitor plates)

When you hook up power the **right** way, the layer gets thinner until the device eventually passes current. When that finally happens, your LED will start to glow.

One final note: *It is possible* to light an LED with just a 1.5V source: use a voltage "step up" circuit. The most common circuit is called a [Joule Thief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_thief).

Answer (score 2):

Their voltage drop (~2 V) is higher than the supply voltage (1.5 V). If the supply voltage is lower than the voltage drop, any diode (including LED) doesn’t conduct at all.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in a way which is useful.  Why do you get no light whatsoever in this case?  OP is expecting a scenario similar to an incandescent bulb, and this answer does nothing to explain why that expectation is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers here, it's also worth pointing out that every LED is different (even by colour).  They all have slightly different 'activation' voltages and breaking limits.

The correct way to be sure that you're not going to blow up your LED while also ensuring that you can expect light is to look at the data sheet for your LED.

Using the datasheet will give you essential experience in

1. Locating said datasheets
2. Reading & understanding them

To get you started, [here's](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/FLR-50T04-HW7+(2012.02.22).pdf) a random one for a white LED from the top of google; which is perhaps a bit more complex than most LED's because "white" isn't a colour in LED land.

There's an incredible amount of information in them, and if you don't understand them I'd suggest that you try, and then post a question again asking about a specific part you don't understand.

Comment: Not only are different colored LEDs different (red are often rated around 2V, while white and blue LEDs regularly operate at 3+V) but even within a color, and sometimes even within a batch they may vary. That's why datasheets often show "Min[imum]", "Typ[ical]", and "Max[imum]" V*f* ratings.